# Class 'MainActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have been coding for a very long time and I've only started using Android Stud last month, I'm having a problem with implementing an OnClickListener.

here's the code that is giving me the error.

I hope my question is clear, else I'll happy to give my code snippet.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button scanBnt;
    private TextView formatText, contentText;

    ....
}
```

Comment: please paste your all code

Comment: sorry I meant to say that I haven't been coding  for a very long time

Comment: please paste your code! it would be easy to understand your problem!

Comment: Have you declared onClick method in your activity?

Comment: les mok please follow this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

for explanation visit [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/)

Comment: Thanks guys, I only realised later that  Ihad missed something.

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Your code
} Solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `View.OnClickListener` interface in your activity. This interface has one abstract method `abstract void onClick(View v)` which you need to override in your activity.

Add the following code to your activity,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Your code
}
```

[Check out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Highlight on the error (OnClickListener) then press Ctrl + Space then click implement method. else you can add the method manually like what @gprathour written.